# Dictionary Extension that Swaps Keys & Values - Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, swap, swift-extensions

## Dictionary Extension - Swap Dictionary Keys & Values

### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

I want to make a function that would take `Dictionary` and return said dictionary, but with its values as the keys and its keys as its respective values. So far, I have made a function to do this, but I cannot for the life of me make it into an `extension` for `Dictionary`.

---

### My Function

```swift
func swapKeyValues<T, U>(of dict: [T : U]) -> [U  : T] {
    let arrKeys = Array(dict.keys)
    let arrValues = Array(dict.values)
    var newDict = [U : T]()
    for (i,n) in arrValues.enumerated() {
        newDict[n] = arrKeys[i]
    }
    return newDict
}
```

---

### Example of Usage:

```swift
 let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]
 let newDict = swapKeyValues(of: dict)
 print(newDict) //["b": 2, "e": 5, "a": 1, "d": 4, "c": 3]
```

---

### Ideal:

```swift
 let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]

 //I would like the function in the extension to be called swapped()
 print(dict.swapped()) //["b": 2, "e": 5, "a": 1, "d": 4, "c": 3]
```

**How do I accomplish this ideal?**

---

Comment: You wouldn't be able to extend ALL dictionaries. Only dictionaries where the values are hashable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A extension of Dictionary could look like this, the `value` which becomes the key must be constrained to `Hashable`

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Hashable {

    func swapKeyValues() -> [Value : Key] {
        assert(Set(self.values).count == self.keys.count, "Values must be unique")
        var newDict = [Value : Key]()
        for (key, value) in self {
            newDict[value] = key
        }
        return newDict
    }
}

let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]
let newDict = dict.swapKeyValues()
print(newDict)
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Right, that's a good challenge for the OP  I added an `assert` expression

Comment: `Set(values).count == count`

Comment: btw you can use Swift 4's `reduce(into:)` method: `return reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.value] = $1.key }`

Comment: Why would you use `assert(condition:, message:)` rather than `precondition(condition:, message:)`?

Comment: @NoahWilder In a Playground there is practically no difference.

Comment: @LeoDabus that’s a fantastic point. I’ll try and update it to reflect that.

Comment: A possible alternative would be to use `newDict.updateValue(key, forKey: value)` – then the return value indicates if same value occurred previously and you don't have to traverse the source dictionary in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As already explained in the other answers, the `Value` type must be
restricted to be `Hashable`, otherwise it can not be the `Key` for the
new dictionary.

Also one has to decide how duplicate values in the source dictionary
should be handled.

For the implementation one can map the source dictionary to a
sequence with keys and values exchanged, and passes that to
one of the initializers

- [`Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) or
- [`Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892961-init).

These differ in how duplicate keys are treated: The first one aborts
with a runtime exception, the second one calls the closure for
conflict resolution.

So a simple implementation is

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {

    func swapKeyValues() -> [Value : Key] {
        return Dictionary<Value, Key>(uniqueKeysWithValues: lazy.map { ($0.value, $0.key) })
    }
}
```

(Mapping the source dictionary *lazily*  avoids the creation of an
intermediate array with all swapped key/value tuples.)

*Example:*

```
let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]
print(dict.swapKeyValues()) //["b": 2, "e": 5, "a": 1, "d": 4, "c": 3]
```

This will crash if the source dictionary has duplicate values.
Here is a variant which accepts duplicate values in the source
dictionary (and “later” values overwrite “earlier” ones):

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {

    func swapKeyValues() -> [Value : Key] {
        return Dictionary<Value, Key>(lazy.map { ($0.value, $0.key) }, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
    }
}
```

*Example:*

```
let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "b"]
print(dict.swapKeyValues()) // ["b": 3, "a": 1]
```

Another option would be to implement this as a dictionary 
initializer. For example:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {

    init?(swappingKeysAndValues dict: [Value:  Key]) {
        self.init(uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.lazy.map( { ($0.value, $0.key) }))
    }
}
```

which crashes in the case of duplicate values in the source dictionary,
or as a throwing initializer

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {

    struct DuplicateValuesError: Error, LocalizedError {
        var errorDescription: String? {
            return "duplicate value"
        }
    }

    init(swappingKeysAndValues dict: [Value:  Key]) throws {
            try self.init(dict.lazy.map { ($0.value, $0.key) },
                          uniquingKeysWith: { _,_ in throw DuplicateValuesError() })
    }
}
```

or as a failable initializer:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {

    struct DuplicateValuesError: Error { }

    init?(swappingKeysAndValues dict: [Value:  Key]) {
        do {
            try self.init(dict.lazy.map { ($0.value, $0.key) },
                          uniquingKeysWith: { _,_ in throw DuplicateValuesError() })
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

*Example (for the failable initializer):*

```
let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]
if let newDict = Dictionary(swappingKeysAndValues: dict) {
    print(newDict) //["b": 2, "e": 5, "a": 1, "d": 4, "c": 3]
}
```

Or, if you are sure that no duplicate values occur:

```
let dict = [1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e"]
let newDict = Dictionary(swappingKeysAndValues: dict)!
```

Comment: Can you say a little more about the purpose of the laziness?

Comment: Why don't you make the initializer throw the error instead of returning nil ? Something like `init(swappingKeysAndValues dict: [Value:  Key]) throws {
        try self.init(dict.lazy.map { ($0.value, $0.key) },
                          uniquingKeysWith: { _,_ in throw DuplicateValuesError() })

    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Actually I had than in an earlier revision, but I replaced it with a failable initializer because there is only a single possible error. – I have added it (and some more options) again. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, what you're asking for is impossible unless the values conform to the `Hashable` protocol. So, a conditional extension is what you're looking for.

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Hashable {
    func keyValueSwapped() -> [Value:Key] {
        var newDict = [Value:Key]()
        keys.forEach { (key) in
            let value = self[key]!
            newDict[value] = key
        }
        return newDict
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map a dictionary to swap keys and values and create a new one using  `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` initializer:

```swift
let dict = ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", ...]
let swappedDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.map {(key, value) in return (value, key)})
```

Just take into account that `Value` type should conform to the Hashable protocol and initializer throws a runtime exception in case of duplicate keys. If original dictionary might have duplicate values, use the `Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` initializer instead.

Answer (score -1):

**Replacing old key with new user define key**

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func switchKey(fromKey: Key, toKey: Key) {
        if let entry = removeValue(forKey: fromKey) {
            self[toKey] = entry
        }
    }
}

var person: [String: String] = ["fName": "Robert", "lName": "Jr"]
person.switchKey(fromKey: "fName", toKey: "firstname")
person.switchKey(fromKey: "lName", toKey: "lastname")
print(person) // ["firstname": "Robert", "lastname": "Jr"]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question wants to change the dictionary `["fName": "Robert", "lName": "Jr"]` to the dictionary `["Robert":"fName", "Jr":"lName"]`.